# Unable to communicate with postgres using docker and django

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I don't achieve to communicate with my database postgres using Docker and Django. Here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/usr/src/web/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 3000:3000
      - 35729:35729
    env_file:
      - database.env
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - database
  
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    
volumes:
  database-data:
```

Here is my database.env :

```
# database.env
POSTGRES_USERNAME=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
POSTGRES_DBNAME=db
POSTGRES_HOST=database
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
PGUSER=admin
PGPASSWORD=pass
PGDATABASE=db
PGHOST=database
PGPORT=5432
DATABASE=db
SQL_HOST=database
SQL_PORT=5432
```

And here is my Dockerfile :

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/web

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
RUN apk add zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev
# install nodejs
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm

# copy project
ADD . .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/src/web/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And there my entrypoint.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "db" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 10
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

exec "$@"
```

I build the docker using that : `docker-compose up -d --build`

Then I type that : `docker-composexec web npm start --prefix ./front/` .

I can access to the frontent : `http://localhost:3000`

But when I do `docker logs database` I got that :

```
2021-01-18 06:31:49.207 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-01-18 06:31:51.640 UTC [32] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"
2021-01-18 06:31:51.640 UTC [32] DETAIL:  Role "admin" does not exist.
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
```

Here is the status :

```
37ee3e314d52        web   "sh /usr/src/web/ent…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 5432/tcp   web
65dfeae57a94        postgres              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                                     database
```

Coud you help me ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the postgres user you are using doesn't exist. You can add some environment variables to database docker-compose to create those (you probably need to create the database, too), Or you can write some script to create those for the first time.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/usr/src/web/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 3000:3000
      - 35729:35729
    env_file:
      - database.env
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - database
  
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin 
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
    
volumes:
  database-data:
```

About postgres image envs you can check [this link](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) .

Comment: thank you, I tried but it does not work :/

Comment: you still get the previous `FATAL` error in database logs? @Peter

Comment: yes :/ but I created the database actually